# Progress bar won't update from for loop

Tags: ios, swift, loops, for-loop, progress-bar

I've been through all similar questions and I can't seem to crack this. I'm trying to iterate through a 10-iteration loop in my xcode project and update the progress bar by 10% every time.

The progress bar doesn't seem to update until the very end, despite my attempts with DispatchQueue.

```
@IBOutlet weak var signingBar: UIProgressView!
@IBOutlet weak var contButton: UIButton!
@IBAction func goButton(_ sender: UIButton) {

        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async {
            for i in 1...10 {

                // run function x times
                runSignings(iterations: 1)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    // now update UI on main thread
                    self.signingBar.setProgress(Float(i/10), animated: true)

                    if i == 10 {
                        self.contButton.isHidden = false
                    }
                    else {
                        self.contButton.isHidden = true
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I expect this to run my function through and update the UI at the end of each for loop, but it is currently not updating the progressbar until all loops are complete.

Comment: Try using [`.userinteractive`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchqos/qosclass/userinteractive) instead of `.utility`.

Comment: How fast is `runSignings` ?

Comment: Same thing happening with .userInteractive. 

runSignings takes about 10 seconds to run 100 iterations, which i'm ultimately looking to run here. I reduced iterations for the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems the `Float(i/10)` should change to `Float(i)/10` because the previous one does the division with two integers then convert to float, it will always return 0 until the `i` reaches to 10.

Also, if I understand your question correctly, you want to update the progress synchronously with each step `i`.

Because you are using `DispatchQueue.main.async` to update the `signingBar` asynchronously in the main thread, so the `for` loop will still go on but not blocked by self.signingBar.setProgress.

If you want to make sure the `signingBar` updates step by step, you can use `DispatchGroup` to wait until the progress bar updated.

```swift
// At each 'i' step

let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()

// run function x times
runSignings(iterations: 1)

DispatchQueue.main.async {
    // now update UI on main thread
    self.signingBar.setProgress(Float(i)/10, animated: true)

    group.leave()
}

group.wait()
```

Hope these above can help you.

Comment: The float mistake sorted this out for me. Unfortunately I couldn’t get the group approach to work, however it seems to be running fine with existing approach